# How to setup tables with varying number of Foreign Key of specific type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Say I have three tables.

```
MenuItem(MenuItemID{PK}, MenuItemName, MenuItemIngredient)

Ingredient(IngredientID{PK}, IngredientName, SupplierID)

Supplier(SupplierID{PK}, SupplierName)
```

Each MenuItem in the MenuItem table can have multiple ingredients.
Each Ingredient in the Ingredient table can have multiple suppliers.

My current way of doing this is to have two extra tables.

```
MenuIngredientLink(MenuItemID{PK}, IngredientID{FK})

IngredientSupplierLink(IngredientID{PK}, SupplierID{FK})
```

Then remove the last column on MenuItem and Ingredient tables.

This doesn't really seem like a good way to do it though.

Any alternatives?

Fairly new to SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Since everything follows a strict `one-to-many relationship`,your original approach to the problem is correct.So no need to introduce two mapping tables.

However, a problem arises in a scenario like this. An ingredient is supplied by many suppliers as well as a supplier provides multiple ingredients, creating a `many-to-many relationship.`Then your approach to a mapping table is the preferred solution.

I have included an external source for your reference. Hope this helps.

[Managing Database Relationships](http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/%22Managing%20database%20relationships%22)

Answer (score 0):

We can make tables with foreign keys as you've specified.  If you start with the Supplier table, you should insert all values required, and it has no foreign key so you have no restrictions.  Next, you insert values into the Ingredients table, since it requires a foreign key to Suppliers.  Lastly, you insert values into the MenuItem table, since it has a foreign key to Ingredient.  You can create the tables first, then add the foreign keys later as I've written below.

```
--Suppliers does not have any foreign keys
CREATE TABLE Supplier (SupplierID int PRIMARY KEY, SupplierName varchar(100))

--Ingredients has a foreign key to Supplier(SupplierID)
CREATE TABLE Ingredient (IngredientID int PRIMARY KEY
                       , IngredientName varchar(100)
                       , SupplierID int)
ALTER TABLE Ingredient ADD FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierID)

--MenuItem has a foreign key to Ingredient(IngredientID)
CREATE TABLE MenuItem (MenuItemID int PRIMARY KEY
                     , MenuItemName varchar(100)
                     , MenuItemIngredientID int)
ALTER TABLE MenuItem ADD FOREIGN KEY (MenuItemIngredientID) REFERENCES Ingredient(IngredientID)
```